# How to boot in recovery mode? It's not in the menu

Tags: grub2

I installed the nvidia drivers and now I have a black screen, so I need to boot in recovery mode to fix it, because ctrl + alt + f1 shows a black screen too.

But for some reason the recovery mode is not in the grub menu.

If I press 'c' I can get a grub command line.

So what's the command for booting ubuntu in recovery mode?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have? It should be under "Advanced Options for Ubuntu", and then you have to select the correct kernel line (as you know).

Comment: @searchfgold6789 I have probably messed something up and removed it. So I need to enter recovery mode using a command.

Comment: So there is nothing under "Advanced Options for Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 3):

While your computer boot, select `Advance menu` for Ubuntu from grub menu. There you can find recovery mode.

If your grub do not have recovery mode, then at grub menu press`e`. It will let you to edit your grub menu. Your grub menu would look somthing like this

```
etparams 'Ubuntu , with Linux 3.6.0-26-generic

recordfail
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <uuid>
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=<uuid> ro ipv6.disable=1 quirt splash $vt_handoff
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic`
```

now change the line

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=<uuid> ro ipv6.disable=1 quirt splash $vt_handoff
```

to

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=<uuid> single
```

which will boot up and show a text-mode terminal with root permissions from where you can make changes.